# How to implement stack safe operations on an immutable tree-like structure?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, tree, immutability

I have an immutable tree-like structure of type:

```
type Data<A> = Empty | Node<A> | Both<A>

type Empty = { tag: Tag.Empty };
type Node<A> = { tag: Tag.Node, value: A };
type Both<A> = { tag: Tag.Both, left: Data<A>, right: Data<A> };
```

What would be a good starting point for implementing *stack safe* operations like `fold`, `map`, and even `flatMap` on this data structure?

Comment: You mean like [this?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwFDAHYFcC2cAqAhgOaJwCiOYMAngDRwByEAJsAwEIQwAWKqtMMDgARQjEIAeAIIA+OAF4KVWnAA+TVsBnyNXXjtQCaQ5dRqKyUYIRYQMAGwsTiALgIkAdJXMoA3MamzGw6lkjWtvZOcC7uRMSewexwEXaOFgBuhA5YwO7S-oHC+jyhSuE2adGxHgklDKlRFg7AAGYw7mISOg2VTSkAlsQ8HaLiUnKFqK1YGADGMAP2cDiEYDKcsgAULOOd4z1wre5bIPkAlIryHOf73RzyCKhwL3AAzgDuAzBzfDvjnhclyer1BcDmhDewni3hUNHc1hgWCgGDINRhPlUyACYNeEKhtUSWgRwCRKLRJDiXiSDCyOTyR3+Ek8dNyl2xz1x4Mh0K8JRJZNRSHRfO4PAYLXa7lWYCZhE8kpgDFa5waQxG0rWcs8UHVSqO7ICnJeaGQQA)

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm aiming for, but without risk of blowing the stack.

Comment: Well you could rewrite it using a while loop

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, you are looking for [Tail recursion optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Take a look at this gist to see if it helps you: https://gist.github.com/Gozala/1697037

Comment: This is a tough nut, b/c your `Both `value constructor is recursive within both its arguments.

Comment: One way would be to use continuation passing style, which we usually try to avoid. Another way would be using a trampoline with a stack that can handle both modulos. This is probably the best option, b/c you only need to implement such a trampoline once.

Comment: Please note that a normal, balanced tree shouldn't exhaust the stack that easily, unless it degenerates to a linked list, that is to say it makes probably sense to conceive an effective self-balancing tree.

Comment: TBH if you have a tree that is deeper than your stack, you have bigger problems than stack safety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the data constructors.

```js
// data Data a = Empty | Node a | Both (Data a) (Data a)
const Empty = { tag: "Empty" };
const Node = value => ({ tag: "Node", value });
const Both = left => right => ({ tag: "Both", left, right });

// data Cont a b = Left (Data a) (Cont a b) | Right b (Cont a b) | Done
const Left = rightQ => next => ({ tag: "Left", rightQ, next });
const Right = leftA => next => ({ tag: "Right", leftA, next });
const Done = { tag: "Done" };

// data Frame a b = Fold (Data a) (Cont a b) | Apply (Cont a b) b
const Fold = data => cont => ({ tag: true, data, cont });
const Apply = cont => result => ({ tag: false, cont, result });
```

Next, we define a stack safe `fold` function.

```js
// fold :: (b -> b -> b) -> (a -> b) -> b -> Data a -> b
const fold = both => node => empty => data => {
    let frame = Fold(data)(Done);

    while (true) {
        const { data, cont, result } = frame;
        const { value, left, right } = data || {};
        const { leftA, rightQ, next } = cont;

        switch (frame.tag ? data.tag : cont.tag) {
        case "Empty":
            frame = Apply(cont)(empty);
            continue;
        case "Node":
            frame = Apply(cont)(node(value));
            continue;
        case "Both":
            frame = Fold(left)(Left(right)(cont));
            continue;
        case "Left":
            frame = Fold(rightQ)(Right(result)(next));
            continue;
        case "Right":
            frame = Apply(next)(both(leftA)(result));
            continue;
        case "Done":
            return result;
        }
    }
};
```

Note that `fold` is a structural fold, but we can use it to define `foldr` which is a traversal fold.

```js
// id :: a -> a
const id = x => x;

// compose :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
const compose = g => f => x => g(f(x));

// flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
const flip = f => y => x => f(x)(y);

// foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Data a -> b
const foldr = func => flip(fold(compose)(func)(id));
```

Finally, we can use `fold` to define `map` and `flatMap`.

```js
// map :: (a -> b) -> Data a -> Data b
const map = func => fold(Both)(compose(Node)(func))(Empty);

// flatMap :: (Data a) -> (a -> Data b) -> Data b
const flatMap = flip(func => fold(Both)(func)(Empty));
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `fold` is a structural fold (as opposed to folds that reduce a collection in some order), because it receives a function for each of its value constructors (`Empty`, `Node`, `Both`). This kind of fold is also called a catamorphism, because it eliminates the type (`Data`). It is regularly more general than the reducing fold but for some types the catamorphism and the reducing fold coincide. Other types again have no reducing fold at all but only a catamorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is some interesting info. Would it suffice to say that data types like Either are limited to reducing folds only? Also, what types would have identical structural and reducing fold signatures?

Comment: For clarification, what do the "rightQ" and "leftA" parameter names stand for in your "Left" and "Right" implementations?

Comment: It stands for "right question" and "left answer". In the `Left` constructor, the right branch hasn't been reduced yet. Hence, it's a question. In the `Right` constructor, the left branch has already been reduced. Hence, it's an answer.

Comment: I chose different names because the names `left` and `right` had already been used in the `Both` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you apparently want an [iterative tree-traversal algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Implementations) that performs some of the standard functional programming operations like `map` and `fold` (aka `reduce`).  The iterative algorithms mentioned in the linked article involve either building a *stack* of node parents, or by maintaining a mapping from each node to its parent.

Here is a possible (not tested extensively, so be careful) implementation for `fold` on your `Data<T>`  which maintains a mapping from a node to its parents while building the desired output structure.  Remember, there are definitely other algorithms out there. I just chose this one because it most clearly expresses how I envision walking through a tree:

```
function fold<T, U>(inData: Data<T>, f: (acc: U, t: T) => U, init: U) {
  const parents: Map<Data<T>, Data<T> | undefined> = new Map();
  let cur: Data<T> | undefined = inData;
  let acc = init;
  while (cur) {
    if ((cur.tag === Tag.Both) && (!parents.has(cur.left))) {
      parents.set(cur.left, cur);
      cur = cur.left;
    } else if ((cur.tag === Tag.Both) && (!parents.has(cur.right))) {
      parents.set(cur.right, cur);
      cur = cur.right;
    } else {
      if (cur.tag === Tag.Node) {
        acc = f(acc, cur.value);
      }
      cur = parents.get(cur);
    }
  }
  return acc;
}
```

If your current node is a `Both` and you haven't yet processed the `left` node, add the current node to he `parents` mapping as the `left` node's parent, and walk leftward down the tree.  Otherwise if the node is a `Both` and you haven't yet processed the `right` node, do the same thing but rightward.  Otherwise you are either processing an `Empty` or `Node` node, or a `Both` node whose `left` and `right` nodes have already been processed... which means you can then process the current node for output and then walk back up to the parent.  Eventually you will try to walk up to the parent of the root of the tree and you're done.

The part that makes this `fold` is that we're running the accumulator callback whenever we process a `Node` node.  It's also important to note that `fold` is generally dependent on the order of traversal (e.g., for lists a left-fold and a right-fold are different), so the above implementation might not be the one you were thinking of (do you want pre-order? in-order? post-order? breadth-first? something else?).

---

Here's an analogous `map` implementation:

```
function map<T, U>(inData: Data<T>, f: (t: T) => U) {
  const parents: Map<Data<T>, Data<T> | undefined> = new Map();
  const mapped: Map<Data<T>, Data<U>> = new Map();
  let cur: Data<T> | undefined = inData;
  while (cur) {
    if ((cur.tag === Tag.Both) && (!parents.has(cur.left))) {
      parents.set(cur.left, cur);
      cur = cur.left;
    } else if ((cur.tag === Tag.Both) && (!parents.has(cur.right))) {
      parents.set(cur.right, cur);
      cur = cur.right;
    } else {
      mapped.set(cur,
        cur.tag === Tag.Both ? ({
          tag: Tag.Both,
          left: mapped.get(cur.left)!,
          right: mapped.get(cur.right)!
        }) : cur.tag === Tag.Empty ? ({
          tag: Tag.Empty
        }) : ({
          tag: Tag.Node, value: f(cur.value)
        })
      );
      cur = parents.get(cur);
    }
  }
  return mapped.get(inData)!;
}
```

It's similar to `fold` but the output processing is different. Building an output node for a `Both` involves using the output nodes already build for each subtree, so this implementation stores a `mapped` map from input nodes to output nodes also, so that can be retrieved later.

---

I'm not going to present `flatMap()` but it would be similar to `map` except your output node for `Node` inputs is produced by the callback function directly instead of needing to be built. You can verify that these do reasonable-ish things for reasonable-ish trees (the Playground Link at the bottom has some examples).

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1JBvAsAKCU0ksCyAGhjnnhMAK5hIAqIA5hkgKJgwAuAnkgF4kAIk49ewgDRIAcgHsAJsiHD5SqUgBCc7gAtBI7XuFIAvhUp8YyACIhuIADwBBAHwGxfJAB9ZiiC7uvka6gTgWeFbInvxC6EgAThAgCnLAADb8DswAXIwsAHQxZgDcEUhRfkqBBvFJKWmZFSx5TMwFahDS9akZ-ABuIOk0EHnOpeWVITVxicm9TdmthSHd84386RAAZtx5dg6Baw19iQCWzLp7SAdObhPY5fBpUNwVSaM39k6vCWfAzHccXKkRa+XaqxBSC2uzyWFwlERS3BBVW0J213hiOxzVyKM6kihiMGw0+wmcwiJZm6FyucKpoLxbQ6-kJCJxeBJIzywk07Ep7Ox5kFeFMbJxf0umKpyOZaJh0pF2NlhRiVLF5yl9KVSLBcp0unFHLwCu1xt1TMKBIZlC5ZIAwux+TaxTbJXS2Cr2sVhcbfULyqYyo9BdsaMB4NwzmkkGAQDBHAxpABVVwACn+t3230Trmk2zyaeuDAAlIJ3Mmy1jsc9gK8kHAksBuFA8gBZeOOW656TdhhBJDhpTbf4QBRA-AQADuSA7MDTJeDONr9bjMGsCnbnb7ea+h1TE+A09n8YXS+xWze8BoCWzh37PkHwGHo4UBkz33PiKnujOWyQabXgkVZUmc2wAYBN4FNkggCEI+p6GWABkSEAQAhI21AtgUuggFAkEJAUColiR5A6pQmHNlABRQBA3AEURGLSEBi42kBBhAYxuxfkKSAQOktFIGBEGcTBcHwSsBrIahaYYSATbYbh+Gce63AkSB5F4JR2G0fRKm0twzE3qxmlIOxQj6VKPGIqYfECcg1bGmuG40XRBFGuaZlQWJcEoiESAAPwAY5nm4ssEIGh5oWmrG8YucwbmccRaFRZ5ql5M5Y4FAlelQapJZoTaoplnkoksLBEnelwXhBWmIWeV6RTVbwRVmCVwWtYy4Usko0h2nk2wMXaJataYI2mSZnnmQ28lYdROUEZNHL+jZUJJNwN7ALF65ZQtH4OAVPHCuUYYRlGMbbHI6QKImKbpvtIB3k4-b5oWCDwHkybSMWZYCBW0j-Gc1yVmRy4vG82mtieCY7r2OYPr4Q47K+h7HnOZ5QpeXm3nuz0DkjI5Hm+QgPdZ6JvO977AEDZM-n+yCLaDHLCWmDE+ZVqJSUgKHoZDOF4QxxGkfV2J87pgtMdjS3GtNSUYmTop2YJLNs+V4l+VzPOyXzSkMflws2mLiV5QZRnAQrlCyybVnqkrDk2izZWsOrzKdBpoVIJTQiDe9ZsFMNFuimxN4GHzC0sRbK2UFHeDrZtnvwPAR3hKG4aRtGW3bOk9hzrdSCphmwBZrjPZIAWAE-eWJepu7NbgzNClQ7nsMlwjT4vkTqMzuj0uW-XmWbtDXbw7u3YHgYR7d6evcmnR2NPbmj4E6+VO3LTv7-ozIt4CrTsVRriHczJcmN-zylQULtfGkbuWEQqZszzWIcWRf8u2-xyvgaze8u5Jh9ayfOaZ89YGXUkza+s0qKuVvgUVSD9A7Yw4tbK4kc7bgI5APaB7lWo-18ghfQtVt4ckapCUyiIYqYPDq-XYBVUrmnStteKxtCL5UKmQtqSBSreTVng1UzVAodXYV1FEap2FjU4WXIaQwRjjU8o-RE00w7MPkWYKEMc5gbQSFtShbkHqHUDCnJ49caAGDXEWD40gAAeVdLGMQBIhHiK4roQCInIZgaYaC9xXG8foBhLrXXMRALoAFLHSF4L9dw1iADUIhJAmBibwaQwhhBeJeM41x7j+ipLrG8Gc3ts7cHRtwCxISInBTCgfQ06JYSej1Hw8Q1JNQeniI1AkSB+pIGsbZMasi+51nSekNxaYpxLWOtgUwQA)